# perl negative look ahead not working on large strings

Tags: perl, regex-lookarounds

The perl negative look ahead is not working on large strings ( length > 40000, in active perl and cygwin perl, version 5.14 ). I tried the same code with `mingw perl 5.8.8` and it stops working for strings with length > 5000.

The code I am using is:

```
my $str = q(A  B);
my $pattern = '(A)(?:(?!(X)).)*(B)';  
if ( $str =~ m/$pattern/ ) {
    print "matched\n";
}
```

This works fine for all three versions of the perl. But when I increase the length of the string by adding spaces, the pattern stops matching.

for e.g.: `my $str = q(A ...some 50000 spaces... B);`

Kindly help.

Comment: do you see error like `Segmentation fault`?

Comment: No segfault; it just stops matching. If I remove the negative look ahead the pattern matches even in the long string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl imposes an internal limit (happens to be a signed 16-bit integer on most systems) on the size of various regex operations to limit stack growth.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593612/1735796) has a very good breakdown of the limit.

From empirical testing, when the space count gets to 32767, that's when you fail, so it's certainly this limit.

Comment: In mingw perl 5.8.8 it is not even matching strings with length > 4500. No warnings or errors are given out.

Comment: Note that in 5.8.*, the regex engine would simply exhaust the stack, and the behavior is undefined. In perl 5.10 and onwards it doesn't use the stack, so that doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: hrunting, @moritz Thanks; How can I increase this limit?

Comment: @user2053270: You probably need to recompile Perl.  See the answer I referenced above for where the limit is defined.  If you change the define to something larger, you'll probably increase it, but I don't know what else in Perl relies on that limit being set to its current limit.  Other than that, you're going to need to find a different way to parse the regex that breaks the match into smaller sizes (probably something more manual).